# Select elements in a sequence

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Consider the following problem:

I have sequence with `2q` elements `{a[1], ..., a[2q]}`, which has been sorted. Then I need to get two sub-sequences `b[i]` and `c[i]`, which satisfy:

1. Both `b[i]` and `c[i]` have `q` elements and `Join({b[i]}, {c[i]}) = {a[i]}`
2. `b[1]` < `b[2]` < ... < `b[q]`
3. `b[i]` < `c[i]` for all `i` = 1...`q`

The difficulty is that I want to get **all** sequence that satisfy the conditions. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to do something with all the sequences, or just calculate how many there are? And c doesn't have to be sorted? I mean for `[1,2,3,4]` do you want both `[1,2],[3,4]` and `[1,2],[4,3]`?

Comment: This is somewhat unclear. A sorted sequence can only be split in exactly one way so that the concatenation of the two halves gives back the original sequence.

Comment: @m69 Yes, c does not to be sorted. And I need all the sequences.

Comment: Does b & c have to be contiguous? for example `[1,2,3,4]` can be split to `[1,3]` & `[2,4]`?

Comment: It might help if you told us *why* you need this. Whatever it is, there's almost certainly a more efficient way to do it. (Unless it's just an arbitrary homework exercise, in which case you'll just have to do what it says and accept the exponential run time and output size.)

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Share your findings / thoughts.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I have tried to find all possible permutations and find the possible ones, but it's obviously too slow and need too much memory since it's at least O(N!).

Comment: It's going to be O(*q*!) in any case, if you really want all the solutions, just because the number of solutions scales as O(*q*!). In fact, just putting the *q* smallest elements of *a* in *b* still leaves *q*! different ways to order the remaining elements in *c*.

Comment: With q=10, my algorithm finds 654,729,075 valid solutions. A naive solution that generates all partitions and permutations and then checks whether they satisfy the conditions would generate 500 times more, but larger values of q will still result in an impractically large number of results. (See updated answer and code example.)

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to partition the input into two halves, while making sure that each partition will lead to a solution. We can do that with a simple recursive method:

Iterate over the input from small to large; for each element, choose whether it goes into subsequence b or c, using these rules:

- If b and c have the same length, add the element to b.
- if b is longer than c, add the element once to b and once to c and recurse with both options.
- If b is full, add all elements to c.

This will give us a number if different partitions, e.g. for the input [1,2,3,4,5,6] they would be:

```
[1,2,3],[4,5,6]
[1,2,4],[3,5,6]
[1,2,5],[3,4,6]
[1,3,4],[2,5,6]
[1,3,5],[2,4,6]
```

Then, for each of these partitions, we have to find the permutations of c which meet the conditions. Again, a simple recursive method will do the trick:

Iterate over b from right to left. For each element, find the elements in c which are greater. If there is only one, put it in the corresponding location in c. If there are severeal, put each of the elements in the corresponding location in c once, and recurse with each option.

For the partition [1,2,4],[3,5,6] in the example, that would lead to:

```
[1,2,4],[x,x,x] <- (3,5,6) ... [1,2,4],[x,x,6] <- (3,5) ... [1,2,4],[3,5,6]
     ^       ^          ^         ^       ^          ^
                           ... [1,2,4],[x,x,6] <- (3,5) ... [1,2,4],[5,3,6]
                                  ^       ^        ^
[1,2,4],[x,x,x] <- (3,5,6) ... [1,2,4],[x,x,5] <- (3,6) ... [1,2,4],[3,6,5]
     ^       ^        ^           ^       ^          ^
                           ... [1,2,4],[x,x,5] <- (3,6) ... [1,2,4],[6,3,5]
                                  ^       ^        ^
```

This code example is a straightforward implementation of the algorithm explained above:

```js
function subsequences(a) {
    var q = a.length / 2;
    partition(0, [], []);

    function partition(pos, part1, part2) {
        var b = part1.slice();                  // create copy
        var c = part2.slice();                  // create copy
        if (b.length == c.length) {
            b.push(a[pos++]);
        }
        while (b.length < q) {
            c.push(a[pos++]);
            partition(pos, b, c);
            b.push(c.pop());
        }
        while (c.length < q) {
            c.push(a[pos++]);
        }
        permute(b, [], c);
    }

    function permute(b, part, set) {
        var pos = set.length - 1;
        for (var i = pos; i >= 0 && set[i] > b[pos]; i--) {
            var c = part.slice();               // create copy
            var s = set.slice();                // create copy
            c[pos] = s.splice(i, 1);
            if (pos == 0) {   // store or process subsequences
                document.write("{" + b + "},{" + c + "}<br>");
            }
            else permute(b, c, s);
        }
    }
}
subsequences([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]); // ascending order
```

The algorithm finds the following number of valid partitions, and valid permutations of c. (For comparison, I've added the number of all partitions and all permutations that a naive solution would need to generate and then check.)

```
 q  partitions     permutations     |   all part.        all perm.
                                    |
 1           1                1     |          1                1
 2           2                3     |          3                6
 3           5               15     |         10               60
 4          14              105     |         35              840
 5          42              945     |        126           15,120
 6         132           10,395     |        462          332,640
 7         429          135,135     |      1,716        8,648,640
 8       1,430        2,027,025     |      6,435      259,459,200
 9       4,862       34,459,425     |     24,310    8,821,612,800
10      16,796      654,729,075     |     92,378  335,221,286,400
```

Running only the first part of the algorithm, we find that for q=20, the number of valid partitions is 6,564,120,420, and the number of valid permutations is probably around 10<sup>22</sup>.

---

*NOTES:*

For the partition function to work correctly, the input sequence needs to be in ascending order. In the permute function, the set of unused values in subsequence c is also kept in ascending order, to make it easier to find the largest values.

The results for any input sequence of n numbers will be similar. In fact, you can replace the input sequence by [0,1,2,3 ... n-1] and then use the values in the results as indexes in the original input sequence. This means that if you need the results for different sequences of n numbers, you only need to run the algorithm once.